# Running impact on lung for smoker

Tags: running, smoking

I'm running once up to twice in the week , mostly saturday morning, one hour from 4-5 a.m, I'm wondering if there is some positive impact on my lung ( smoker lung) other than just normal positive impact a runner can get? I mean like somehow it cleans nicotine from my lung? I'm sorry if this is a dummy question ( as some might say, " well smoking is bad anyway") but as you know that nobody smoking doesn't realize the risks they can probably get from the bad activity, but we're smoking because we get addicted, and quitting on it, is not a short time goal). One thing for sure that I always notice is that during 2 days, after running, I feel like a ciggarete tastes very bad (like food without salt, some think like that). I need some advices. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Increased blood circulation helps remove toxins from body. I don't think there is much else to say on the topic. Other benefits are the "normal" ones - increasing lung capacity and decreasing blood pressure.

Comment: Interesting! I wanna read it more?

Comment: I disagree with VSO. There is a lot more to say. The heart plays a big role on the lungs and exercise helps with this. I'll post an answer with more helpful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, exercise will increase your health and your body's operating efficiency. **Things like [stroke volume](http://www.cheetah-medical.com/content/introduction-stroke-volume), [lung efficiency and capacity](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/if-a-persons-lung-size-ca/), and red blood cell efficiency [including oxygen and co2 delivery efficiency](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3824146/).** See the Diagram below.

[image: Circulatory system diagram]
Not only does blood efficiency increase but so does red blood cell production and the exchange of nutrients/wastes at the capillaries in the liver, kidneys, brain and the lungs. Potentially, your cognitive functions will be more efficient as well or, **in short**, you can become smarter (arguable of course, depending on how you define intelligence).

As your blood operates better, you will get rid of toxins/waste from all areas of your body thereby lowering your chances of cancer and increasing your energy and the overall health of all your other cells, even non-skeletal muscles. This effect is very noticeable to people who have had a very sedentary lifestyle or who have been poisoning themselves with smoking. **In short, exercising will make you feel like a different person.**

[More about anatomy and exercise.](https://books.google.com/books?id=YHZtv4XKeCMC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=red%20blood%20cell%20delivery%20exercise&source=bl&ots=2hU6YrSYX_&sig=QEGaIexDhTNu1zUS33j839ZTE1E&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiD45_LsKfLAhULx4MKHVr5AaYQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=red%20blood%20cell%20delivery%20exercise&f=false)

**You must exercise caution, however,** (hey that's pretty punny) exercise can undo *some* damange to the lungs but not most, so **QUIT SMOKING! ;)** You also need to be aware of low oxygen symptoms such as dizziness, lightheadedness, etc and heed these warning signs or you may pass-out on the treadmill for example and become injured.  Also, you're at greater risk of heart disease so take it easy and slowly work your way up. Don't push your self too hard and consult your doctor.

More articles about smoking and exercise:
[HealthyLiving](http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/can-exercise-smoke-cigarettes-10406.html)
[LiveStrong](http://www.livestrong.com/article/482679-can-you-exercise-smoke/)
[FitnessBlender](https://www.fitnessblender.com/blog/stop-smoking-exercise-plan-how-exercise-can-help)

[More on stroke volume.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFIciyGWJb4)

Comment: Hey thank you, yes i'm in process of quiting. Thanks again

Comment: Your welcome, hope it was helpful.